# How we can put Floating action button on top of any layout

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am doing some operation on floating action button . I have a list view and showing google ad at bottom of my screen, The floating  action button is showing at same place (bottom|end). so  action button is hiding the ad.

I want shift the Floating  action button little above the ad linear layout.

Please have a look the image: 
[image]

My code is look like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/fab"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
     android:src="@drawable/fav"
     android:adjustViewBounds="false" />


adLayoutId is ad layout id
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `RelativeLayout`, and as we know, later children in a `RelativeLayout` tend to float over earlier children in a `RelativeLayout`.

So, to have a FAB float over of any layout, make sure that the FAB is defined after all views (at the end of the XML layout).

If you use `android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"` the best way to manipulate FAB is set dependencies between views, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adLayoutId"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adLayoutId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/adLayoutId"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/fav"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Floating action button always will be above the ad linear layout, and independent from ad layout size.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
       />
```

Answer (score 1):

These two lines inside the fab button helped me solved this problem:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Here's the entire code I used for the button alone:

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_newStudent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />
```

Answer (score 0):

THESE TWO LINES ARE IMPORTANT.

android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the entire code I used for the floatingactionbutton:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/bg_bottomnav"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">

    <!-- Bottom Navigation View -->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottomicon_color"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_circle_24"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/bottomicon_color"/>
    
    <View
    android:id="@+id/snackbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="252dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

Add a bottom Margin of 55dp which is the size of Admob Banners

This line in either the floating button or enclosing layout.

`android:layout_marginBottom="55dp`